# Libreoffice 7.4 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: updates, 22.04

Will Ubuntu 22.04 automatically update Libreoffice to 7.4.x or it will keep Libreoffice 7.3.x forever ?

Thank you

Comment: No. Also, forever is a long time. Ubuntu's standard support is five years.

Comment: Thank you Mike. no for you means no update or no keep ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of some major event to change the plan, LibreOffice debs in the Ubuntu Repositories are NOT bumped to higher versions during the life of a release. This is the same way most applications are handled.

- "major event" means some critical security vulnerability or bug that is easier to mitigate by bumping the version instead of the normal patching.
- Newer releases of Ubuntu (like 22.10) do include newer releases of applications (including LibreOffice).
- PPAs with newer versions are often available. Remember to uninstall the PPA version before your next release-upgrade to avoid breaking your system.
- Snaps with newer versions are also available.

Comment: Thank you for your time